# Getting Exception handling error while debugging the Windows Phone Test Framework by expensify

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I have set up the environment for Windows Phone test Framework in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
While debugging Unit Test using Resharper, i am getting exception handling error.

> "A first chance exception of type
>   'WindowsPhoneTestFramework.Server.Core.AutomationException'  occurred
>   in TechTalk.SpecFlow.DLL"

How can i fix it and run my scripts for WP7 emulator?

Answer (score 2):

WPTF works by setting up a SOAP server on the desktop host which the application then connects to, it looks like the phone can't contact the host. This could be because it hasn't been setup or because it didn't have permission to start.

From the [WPTF readme](https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework):

> •
>   For some script runners, then you may need to change script runner to have the 32-big flag set - try to find a 32-bit alternative (e.g. nunit-console-x86.exe) - or (at worst) use CorFlags.exe to change your test-runner.
>       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\CorFlags.exe" "your target.exe" /32BIT+
>
> •
>   The server part of the code opens a WCF service on http://localhost:8085 - it needs permission to do this - use:
>        netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8085/ user=\

Have you tried these? It might be worth getting a developer involved if you aren't comfortable with the instructions.